# Plot of bars with height data in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a matrix `{{2, 1, 2, 2, 1}, {1, 3, 0, 1, 2}, {3, 3, 0, 3, 1}, {1, 1, 2, 1, 1}}`, and I want to generate a 3d plot such as there are a total of 4*5=20 bars.

There is a bar of height 2 based at the little square (1, 1) (i.e. the square formed on the x-y plane by the points {{0,0},{0,1},{1,1},{1,0}}),

another bar of height 1 based at the little square (1,2) (i.e. the square formed on the x-y plane by the points {{0,1},{0,2},{1,2},{1,0}}),

...

another bar of height 3 based at the little square (2,2) (i.e. the square formed on the x-y plane by the points {{1,1},{2,1},{2,2},{1,2}})

...

and another bar of height 1 based at the little square (4,5) (i.e. the square formed on the x-y plane by the points {{3,4},{4,4},{4,5},{3,5}})

I cannot find an easy way to do this. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data = {{2,1,2,2,1}, {1,3,0,1,2}, {3,3,0,3,1}, {1,1,2,1,1}};

BarChart3D[data, ChartLayout -> "Grid", BarSpacing -> 0]
```

[image]

**Edit**

Updating after wiki-specifying the question :

```
BarChart3D[data, ChartLayout -> "Grid", BarSpacing -> {0, 0},
                 LabelingFunction -> (Row[{#1, Reverse[#2 - 1], Reverse[#2]}] &), 
                 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

[image]

Here the both x and y-spacings vanish.  Setting the cursor on a given bar you get `z{x_min,y_min}{x_max,y_max}`, on the top-red i.e. : `2{4,1}{5,2}`

Comment: May I ask how to specify the base coordinates for the bars? Also, even with the option BarSpacing -> 0 if you rotate the plot, there is still some spacing in the other dimension. How to get rid of these spacing?

Answer (score 4):

What you want is [`BarChart3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BarChart3D.html).

Note, this function exists in two incarnations:

- There is a [`BarChart3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/BarCharts/ref/BarChart3D.html) in the `BarCharts` package. This function does what you want out of the box, but is deprecated in Mathematica 7+.
- Then there's a [`BarChart3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BarChart3D.html) in the main namespace (Mathematica 7+ only), which can do what you want as well, but needs to be passed the option `ChartStyle -> "Grid"` to display the result you want.

Here is some example code for both of these:

#### Mathematica 6 and prior

```
<<BarCharts`;
data = {{2, 1, 2, 2, 1}, {1, 3, 0, 1, 2}, {3, 3, 0, 3, 1}, {1, 1, 2, 1, 1}};
BarChart3D[data]
```

#### Mathematica 7 and later

```
data = {{2, 1, 2, 2, 1}, {1, 3, 0, 1, 2}, {3, 3, 0, 3, 1}, {1, 1, 2, 1, 1}};
BarChart3D[data, ChartLayout -> "Grid"]
```

Comment: +1, Great. May I ask how to specify the base coordinates for the bars? Also, even with the option `BarSpacing -> 0` if you rotate the plot, there is still some spacing in the other dimension. How to get rid of these spacing?